# altering hours in posixct array in r

Tags: r, posixct

Say if I have an array that contains DateTimes:

```
> head(DateTime)
[1] "2010-04-23 13:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 14:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 15:00:00 UTC"
[4] "2010-04-23 16:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 17:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 18:00:00 UTC"
```

and another array of hourly values:

```
> head(hour_vals)
[1] 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

How would I change the hours in DateTime to be equivalent to the hours in hour_vals, for example:

```
> head(FinalResult)
[1] "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC"
[4] "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC" "2010-04-23 20:00:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
DateTime.lt <- as.POSIXlt(DateTime)
DateTime.lt$hour <- 20
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DateTime.lt)
```

Unlike `POSIXct`, which stores datetimes as a single number (seconds since the epoch), `POSIXlt` stores them as tuples of seconds, minutes, hours, etc., which can be accessed directly (see `?POSIXlt` for details). `POSIXct` has a smaller memory footprint, and is therefore the preferred datatype for datetime objects, but for tasks such as this, temporarily converting to `POSIXlt` is simple and effective.

Comment: A word of caution: altering `POSIXlt` objects like this can potentially yield nonsensical date-times: e.g. `DateTime.lt <- as.POSIXlt("2013-03-10 01:00:00", tz="America/Chicago"); DateTime.lt$hour <- 2`.  DST started at 2am in this TZ, so the updated `DateTime.lt` didn't actually exist.